# Why is /tmp getting cleaned out in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: systemd, cleanup, tmp

I want to keep files newer than 7 days in `/tmp` between boots. Prior to 15.04 I  did this by setting `TMPTIME=7` in `/etc/default/rcS`. But with 15.04 and the  replacement of upstart by systemd, this doesn't work.  As far as I understand, the approach is through the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` and the  possibility of overriding it with `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`.  But I have the default `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` which has the line:

```
D /tmp 1777 root root -
```

The final `-` means, according to the `tmpfiles.d` man page, that no automatic cleanup is done.  But, in fact my `/tmp` is cleaned out with every reboot and I could not find a way to stop that. Why is `/tmp` getting cleaned out, and how can I change that?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to keep files in /tmp after reboots?

Comment: I often download files or create scratch files that I may need for a day or two but don't want to keep permanently, so I have been keeping them in /tmp with a 7 day day clean out period.  Its a workflow that has been effective for me for many years, and I would like to keep it up.  The documentation seems to suggest that the tmpfiles.d system is designed to support this, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: For this I use a "Temp" directory in my home directory, eg ~/Temp as `/tmp` has a system specific purpose and I don't want to pollute the global `/tmp`.  That said, good luck on solving your problem but I'm sorry I don't personally know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by creating the file /etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf containing:

```
# Override cleaning of /tmp in vendor /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf,
# as documented in tmpfiles.d(5), for Kubuntu 15.04 and above that
# use systemd.  First char is 'd', instead of 'D', to avoid cleaning.

d /tmp 1777 root root -
```

Comment: /tmp to me is a sort of recycle bin which I want to clean by my personal preferences. It is a valuable space for script debugging and thus should have a more sophisticated clean mechanism than just removing things at reboot. Using /var/tmp for more persistent stuff means to apply a cleanup process to that dir too so I'd like to leave it in /tmp in the 1st place.