# Why is ubuntu ignoring TMPTIME?

Tags: 16.04

I have an application that stores some files in the `/tmp/appdata` folder.
I store these files so that the application does not have to copy these files from the network every time it is run.
I want to store these files for `90` days. For this I have set the value of **`TMPTIME`** to `90` in the file `/etc/default/rcS`.
The problem is that ubuntu seems to be ignoring this value. Every time I restart the ubuntu server the files in `/tmp` folder are cleaned and the `appdata` folder is deleted.
Why is happening? and How to fix this?

The version of ubuntu is given below.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: `/tmp` is temporary folder. Everything you put into it will be erased at startup. You must choose another folder to store this content. I suggest you to use `/opt`, `/usr/share`, or any else.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I want to use this location as cache (sort off) and control whether it is over written is inside the application.

Comment: Again, *`/tmp` is temporary folder. Everything you put into it will be erased at startup.*

Comment: Found the answer [why is tmp getting cleaned out in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625455/why-is-tmp-getting-cleaned-out-in-ubuntu-15-04)